# wp-admin redirect loop when behind apache reverse proxy

Tags: apache-2.4, redirect, haproxy, wordpress

Its my first post in Server Fault, so I'm sorry for any faux pas :)

Problem: When I try to access "http://dummy_server/wp-admin" that is behind an apache acting as a WAF, it gets stuck in an infinite redirect loop.

The full configuration of the HAProxy and the WAF can be found here https://www.haproxy.com/blog/scalable-waf-protection-with-haproxy-and-apache-with-modsecurity/

For what I could investigate, if I access the dummy_server while turning off the apache VH (i.e. only using the HA proxy) when I do a GET to dummy_server/wp-admin, the server responds with

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Wed, 20 Feb 2019 19:00:49 GMT
Location: https://dummy_server/wp-login.php?redirect_to=.....
```

Then the browser redirects to dummy_server/wp-login and waits for user credentials.

Nevertheless, if I do a GET to dummy_server with the WAF activated, the **Location** header changes to

```
Location: https://dummy_server/wp-admin
```

and the procceds to get stuck in a redirect loop.

If I turn of the WAF configuration (I'm using modsecurity) so that the apache only acts as a reverse proxy, but the problem persists.

Here is the VM configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:90>
       <IfModule mod_security2.c>
                Include /etc/apache2/owasp-modsecurity-crs/crs-setup.conf
                SecRuleEngine On
                SecRequestBodyAccess On
                SecResponseBodyAccess On
        </IfModule>
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyRequests Off
        ProxyVia Off
        ProxyPass / http://192.168.57.22:81/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.57.22:81/
</VirtualHost>
```

I've been searching in the site, but I haven'f found anything that helps me in my current predicament. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: That looks like the configuration of your Apache reverse proxy. We need to look at the configuration of your origin server.

Comment: Indeed, that is the apache reverse proxy conf, I thought the problem related with it. With origin server you mean the HA configuration?

Comment: No, I mean the origin server, which is the actual web server at the end of your long chain.

Comment: Sorry for the tardiness, It took me some time to get the config, but it was as Tero Kilkanen said, the problem was with the https

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem here is that your Internet-facing web server is using `https`, but the communication between that server and Apache2 is `http`.

Then, Wordpress sees that the incoming connection is coming in with `http` protocol, but the site URL has been defined to be `https`. That is why Wordpress sends the redirect to the user.

I have fixed this issue by adding the following line to `wp-config.php`.

```
$_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';
```

I don't know if this is the preferred way of handling this issue, but it works for me.

You also need to have proper `Host` headers sent to to the proxied server too.

Comment: Thank you! that also worked for me, but as `$_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';` because `on` is not defined in my end

Comment: That is a very good observation, being quoted as the string is the correct way, I updated the answer. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 0):

In your haproxy.cfg in frontend section add:

```
http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Proto https if { ssl_fc }
```

WordPress reads this header and sets `$_SERVER['HTTPS']` to `'on'` when it is present and behaves correctly.